# Is there anyway to handle SQL Error other than try catch block in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

In Spring Boot in @ControllerAdvice error handler, we can provide Exceptions & what to do for the following. But, it doesn't work with Error.

DataIntegrityViolationException ca handle some SQL errors like more length, duplicate, etc.
But, some errors come under SQLError.

I tried adding SqlError.class, Error.class. But, it didn't capture as it handles only Exception 
@ExceptionHandler

Temporarily, I am handling it in a try-catch block. And, if not handled without try-catch also fine, but it gives query result in REST response saying this field this error, etc. Which is vulnerable to show to the user.
So, if it can be handled globally, we will just avoid those parts.

Comment: SQLError? Do you mean SqlException?

Comment: yes, I think I just saw a block insider log instead of an error. Is it not handled in @ControllerAdvice as these are run time errors?

Comment: How does your ControllerAdvice look like?

Comment: @ControllerAdvice, having authentication 401, authorization 403, field level method argument 422, DataIntegrityViolation (for duplicate, length check) SQL, at the end Exception.class to wrap which are not captured

Comment: Show the code please